# Why this updating fails?

Tags: android, textview

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_marginTop="153dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
android:onClick="adelante"
android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.pruebamusica;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  MediaPlayer mp[]=new MediaPlayer[6];
  public TextView tv;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++){
      String sonido = "raw/g" + (i+1);
      int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(sonido, null, this.getPackageName());
      mp[i]= MediaPlayer.create(this, resID);
    }
  }

  public void adelante (View v){
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++){
      tv.setText("Sonido " + i);
      mp[i].start();
      do { // ESPERAMOS A QUE EL SONIDO ACABE.
      } while (mp[i].isPlaying());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to play 6 sounds of 3 to 5 seconds, and I want to update `textView1` in every loop of the for{}, but `textView1` is only updated to "Sonido 5".
Any suggestions?

Comment: I think as you are playing very short length sounds, the textview might be updated very quickly and you are not able to see the earlier updates of the text view which are from 0 to 4. Are you sure that its playing all the sounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adelante will bock the UI thread. The UI will not update until all tasks are completed. So you only can see the final result.
Please use the Handler and thread to update the UI.

You should do it with AsyncTask:

```
MySyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
      protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
          for (int i=0; i<6; i++){
             publishProgress(i);
             mp[i].start();

             do { // ESPERAMOS A QUE EL SONIDO ACABE.
             } while (mp[i].isPlaying());
         }
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         tv.setText("xxx play:" + i);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
```

You're going from 0 to 5.  If you want to go 1-6, you need to do `tv.setText("Sonido " + (i+1));`

Comment: It's not the origin of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this in `onCreate()`.  You should only use `onCreate()` to do the minimum neccesary to setup the activity.

In this case, the UI is not even built yet so any updates will show only the last one, when you finally allow `onCreate()` to return and the activity to build the UI.

Use `onResume()` or later.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, is very dangerous to use a do{}while() loop to wait for the end of the music, because of it harvest resources doing nothing, so, you must think about it in an asynchronous way.

I recommend you to manage the player as an AsyncTask (A MUST! in Android Programming), in which, at "onPreExecute()" you can refresh the tv TextView and, when it finishes, out of the asynctask, firing a new play.

Another option is using a "Listener" to wait the end of the play.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any loop ,,,... but if it is regarding about time . i.e you want to play sound for some seconds your for loop will get the last i.e most recently updated value of i...
so i you want to get the updated value of each and every second  you have to use Handler() for updating each value every a second..... that why you are getting the most recently value of i in for loop